# Unable to find dependency com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:[10.2.4]

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

I imported Firebase Analytics into my Unity project. I updated the Google Play Services, among a few packages, in Android SDK Manager. When I tried to compile my Unity project, I got the following errors:

1)

```
Unable to find dependency com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:[10.2.4] in paths ($SDK\extras\android\m2repository, $SDK\extras\google\m2repository, $SDK\extras\android\m2repository, $SDK\extras\google\m2repository).

com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:[10.2.4] was referenced by:
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace() in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Environment.cs:line 227
   at Google.JarResolver.Dependency..ctor(System.String group, System.String artifact, System.String version, System.String[] packageIds, System.String[] repositories)
   at Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport.GetDependencies(Google.JarResolver.Dependency dep, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 repoPaths)
   at Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport.GetTransitiveDependencies(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 dependencies, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 repoPaths)
   at Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport.FindMissingDependencyPaths(System.String destinationDirectory, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 ByRef dependencyPaths, Google.JarResolver.ExplodeAar explodeAar)
   at GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1.DoResolution(Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport svcSupport, System.String destinationDirectory, Google.JarResolver.OverwriteConfirmation handleOverwriteConfirmation, System.Action resolutionComplete)
   at GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver.Resolve(System.Action resolutionComplete)
   at GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver.AutoResolve()
   at UnityEditor.EditorApplication.Internal_CallUpdateFunctions() in C:\buildslave\unity\build\artifacts\generated\common\editor\EditorApplicationBindings.gen.cs:line 197

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:<PlayServicesResolver>m__0(String, LogLevel)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:Log(String, LogLevel, Boolean)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:FindCandidate(Dependency, List`1)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:GetDependencies(Dependency, List`1)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:GetTransitiveDependencies(Dictionary`2, List`1)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:FindMissingDependencyPaths(String, Dictionary`2&, ExplodeAar)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:DoResolution(PlayServicesSupport, String, OverwriteConfirmation, Action)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Resolve(Action)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:AutoResolve()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

2)

```
ResolutionException: Cannot find candidate artifact for com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:[10.2.4]
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport.GetDependencies (Google.JarResolver.Dependency dep, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 repoPaths)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport.GetTransitiveDependencies (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 dependencies, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 repoPaths)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport.FindMissingDependencyPaths (System.String destinationDirectory, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2& dependencyPaths, Google.JarResolver.ExplodeAar explodeAar)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1.DoResolution (Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport svcSupport, System.String destinationDirectory, Google.JarResolver.OverwriteConfirmation handleOverwriteConfirmation, System.Action resolutionComplete)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver.Resolve (System.Action resolutionComplete)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver.AutoResolve ()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication.Internal_CallUpdateFunctions () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/editor/EditorApplicationBindings.gen.cs:197)
```

I got the same errors when I went to Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android Resolver > Resolve Client Jars.

What should I do to remove the errors?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite is not there in the table. Looking for com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by updating the Google Mobile Ads unity package.

Comment: can you please ley us know the steps to update Google Mobile Ads unity package?

Comment: Download GoogleMobileAds.unitypackage at https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases. Then import the package in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it.

Go to the file in your project Assets/GooglePlayGames/PluginVersion.cs, 
inside change the PlayServicesVersionConstraint to "10.2.1" (the default value is"10+").

Save and go to unity.

In the menu go to Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android Resolver > Resolve Clients Jar. If the program ask you about change of the version press ok.
And the app should it work.

PS: Sorry for my English, is too bad :( .

Comment: I am unable to find that path and that file!

Comment: compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.4' use this dependency

Comment: and also add apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: How do I do those specifically?

Comment: those for the unity framework just forget about it if you are facing problem in android then use these which is mention in above comments i hope it will solve your problem

Comment: I have done this (changed to 10.2.1. in the .cs file) but unfortunately it still gives me the exact same ResolutionException error when clicking to resolve jars in Unity